# How to link two documents of different collection in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, collections, document

I need to know to link how to link two documents of different collection in firebase.

The method to link them.

Comment: What do you mean by "link"? Do you want to mimic the concept of SQL foreign keys in a NoSQL database?

Comment: Please edit your question and answer Renaund's question, and please also respond using @.